# htaccess multiple rewrite rules for different GET variables

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use htaccess Rewrite Rules to map multiple GET variables, but not all the variables are required.  I have ordered the variables so that x is always required, if y is set, then z must be set, etc.  So I need the mappings to look like this:

```
example.com/section/topic/sub
```

to map to

```
example.com/?x=section&z=topic&y=sub
```

However the following code causes Internal Error, but if I only have one Rewrite Rule, it works.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ([^/]+)/?   [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  ?x=$1&z=$2&y=$3&r=$4    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  ?x=$1&z=$2&y=$3    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  ?x=$1&z=$2    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$  ?x=$1    [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

I also need to ensure the url *can* have a trailing /, but does not require it.

As you can probably tell, I am new to htaccess.

Thank You

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Don't know what `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ([^/]+)/?` is doing.
2. Make trailing slash optional by using `/?$`
3. Check for files/directories once at the top and skip applying the rules form them.

You can have your rules like this in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]


RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?x=$1&z=$2&y=$3&r=$4 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?x=$1&z=$2&y=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?x=$1&z=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?x=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: There is one problem I have encountered, which is that if you enter an invalid url, it opens index.php many times inside one another.  Any Thoughts on how to have an Error come up instead?

Comment: Anything that isn't a real link.  x is a .php file that is read within index.php, so if I have example.com/docs and there isn't a docs.php, then index.php is opened within itself again and again.

Comment: Do you have some other code than I what I have in my answer here (like hiding .php extension)?

Comment: I believe there is on the server, but I don't have access to it.  I have managed to create a workaround by including a check within index.php

Comment: This helped me stop bashing my head into the desk.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're going through a lot of trouble to do something that can be achieved in just one rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/*(.*)/*(.*)/*(.*)/*$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4
```

This will always return *something like* the following in `PHP`:

```
//var_dump($_GET);

array(4) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(#) "VALUE"
  ["b"]=>
  string(#) "VALUE"
  ["c"]=>
  string(#) "VALUE"
  ["d"]=>
  string(#) "VALUE"
}
```

Where the `VALUE` will either be *empty* if not set in the URL or the value if it is set.

**N.B.** You may also need to add the conditions that it is not an actual file/directory; depending on your site structure.

### Example

Given:

```
http://example.com/section/topic/sub
```

The URL it's transformed to will be:

```
http://example.com/index.php?a=section&b=topic&c=sub&d=
```

Which will show up in `PHP` as:

```
//var_dump($_GET);

array(4) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(7) "section"
  ["b"]=>
  string(5) "topic"
  ["c"]=>
  string(3) "sub"
  ["d"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```